# External webpack module for electron does not work after building

Tags: webpack, electron, electron-builder

I'm trying to use the `archiver` module in my Electron app. This caused errors during development at first because I didn't add it to my webpack externals:

```
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.externals({
      archiver: "require('archiver')"
    })
  },
```

This worked in development but turns out that after building the app for production and it comes up with a new error after launching it:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'archiver'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\user\workspace\my-app\dist_electron\win-unpacked\resources\electron.asar\renderer\init.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:627)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (C:\Users\user\workspace\my-app\dist_electron\win-unpacked\resources\electron.asar\common\reset-search-paths.js:41)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16)
    at Object.4f22 (app.107e8b71.js:1)
    at o (app.107e8b71.js:1)
    at Object.d7c3 (app.107e8b71.js:1)
    at o (app.107e8b71.js:1)
    at Module.f8da (app.107e8b71.js:1)
```

How do I solve this?

I'm using `vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder` to build my Electron app.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that in `vue.config.js` I used this:

```js
   chainWebpack: config => {
     config.externals({
        archiver: "require('archiver')"
     })
   }
```

But because I have `vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder`, I should have used:

```js
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      externals: ['archiver'],
      builderOptions: {
      etc...
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I was banging my head against a wall for days trying to figure this out until I came across this.